# checked checkbox dynamically with value from database in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

I have made ​​a dynamic checkboxes based on existing data in the database. 
For storage to the database, I use the id contained in each of checkboxes. the problem is, when I want to edit the data and returns the value of the checkboxes, the checkbox is not checked dynamically. 
What I need to know is how to make the checkboxes checked dynamically when the edit page is loaded according to the id that is already stored in the database.

here some of my code

in Edit View

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.ModulList) // for generated dynamic checkboxes

   {
     <tr>
       <td>

        <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="SelectedModuls" Value ="@item.ModulID">@item.ModulName  // Got stuck in this session


       </td>
      </tr>
    }
```

in Controller

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
       return View(DAM.GetMenuById(id));
    }
```

In Data Access Function GetMenuById(id)

```
public MenuModel GetMenuById(int id)
    {
        MenuModel menus = new MenuModel();
        menus.ModulList = GetModuleList();
        menus.StatusList = MenuStatus;

        try
        {
             string query = string.Format(@"SELECT DISTINCT M.MenuID, M.MenuName, Md.ModulID, Md.ModulName from Menu M
                                            LEFT JOIN MenuModul MM ON MM.MenuID = M.MenuID 
                                            LEFT JOIN Modul Md ON Md.ModulID = MM.ModulID 
                                            where M.MenuID = {0} AND M.IsDeleted = 0", id);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);

            for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                menus.MenuID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["MenuID"]);
                menus.MenuName = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["MenuName"]);
                menus.ModulID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ModulID"]);
                menus.ModulName = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["ModulName"]);
            }

          // I fetch ModulID and ModulName data for return the checkbox value when I want to edit.

            da.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return menus;
    }
```

Please help, and I will be very grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox inputs should have unique names, as those are used in the POST array. Radiobutton inputs share a name, since you only want one "value" POSTed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add checked attribute, like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" name="SelectedModuls" Value ="@item.ModulID" checked>@item.ModulName
```